# Angular taking DOM snapshot

Tags: dependency-injection, angularjs, clone, angularjs-directive

I am trying to record the content of a div which is populated using ng-repeat, sort of like taking a snapshot of that div at certain moments so that I don't have to write more code to persist data.

link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
                scope.game = game;

```
            var $element = $(element),
            $clone = $element.children().clone();

            scope.$watch('someVariable',function(array){
                if (array[array.length - 1] === scope.id){
                    record($compile($clone)(scope));
                    console.log($compile($clone)(scope));
                }
            },true);

        }
```

I've been trying variations of code like this but could not get any luck, I've never been able to deep copy the content of the div generated by ng-repeat

any suggestions on how I could copy the exact dynamically genereted content of the div at certain point of time?

Comment: Why do you need to do this? I'm sure there's a better way.  Your data should produce dom output, then you can just copy the data.

Comment: Because persisting the data brings too much trouble, it requires a lot of more code, and the data has no other uses

Comment: But you already had the data to put into the ngRepeat in the first place, which generated the DOM. Why can't you use that?

Comment: because it's a pretty complicated process, yes the content is generated by ng-repeat, but there are a lot of layers of ng-repeats, angular bindings, ng classes, and heavy calculations involved, and the content itself has 24 states. Since everything is dynamically generated, if I am to display a big number of records it will cause big lag

Comment: could anyone give a relevant answer to this..in the linking function I  guess the data is not linked yet, doing console logs and jquery trials confuses the heck out of me. I guess I'll just use jQuery for this

Answer (score 1):

If you have the data to present in a ng-repeat you already have the data in the model, you just have to save a snapshot of that data to other object in the Scope. You should manipulate the data in the controller instead of trying to access the DOM directly, this is a big no no in angularjs. Then if you need a Div to reuse, just make a Directive that knows how to present those snapshots you saved in the model.

Comment: again as I said in the comments, there is quite a lot of complication before displaying the data in the pattern I need. I don't want to waste CPU resources on recalculating all the patterns and displaying them. Well I am manipulating DOM in directives, that is acceptable right?